# Jquery color picker to change text color

Tags: jquery, text, color-picker

I am using [farbtastic color picker](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) and working fine but now I need to change the text color using this plugin.

This is what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/g2hZy/15/

This is my code:

With this the text color is not changing and not showing me the hex value too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function (color) {
             $("#colorpicker").style("color", color);
         });

     });
</script>
```

Text input control:

```
<input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" />
```

Color picker placeholder:

```
<div id="colorpicker"></div>
```

This is my text input:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
```

Now if I write anything and change the color from color picker I need to change the text forecolor from "Text1" input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colorpicker').farbtastic(function(color) {
        // sets the color for both the 'color' and 'Text1' inputs
        $("#color, #Text1").css("color", color);
        // updates the 'color' input to the currently-selected color
        $("#color").val(color);
    });

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g2hZy/21/).

Comment: Thanks David for saving so much of time  for me and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user944919, FYI- This solution/demo is not working in Safari.

Comment: Ok no probs I will try to manage but I need to know how do I give the basic color to the text.And thanks that you made me know that:)

Comment: @Sparky672, are there any errors produced? It works in Chromium 14 on Ubuntu, and Webkit browsers are usually fairly consistent...
User944919: See the edited answer and demo.

Comment: Ooops!  My mistake!  I see that it changes the color of the text itself... I had not typed in anything!

Comment: @Sparky672, why, you silly-Billy... ;) and no worries at all, it did seem an odd failure/bug. But, honestly, don't they all? Thanks for offering your help, though; it's much appreciated! =)

Comment: @David, no problem... I was working on it too but when the OP said he wanted "foreground" color to change, I guess I got my "fore" mixed up with my "back".  Lol.

Answer (score 1):

To change text color you can also use something like this -

```
<input type="text" name="text_color" id="text_color" value=""/>

<div id="text_picker"></div>

$('#text_picker').farbtastic(ChangeTextColor);

function ChangeTextColor(color)
{
    $('#text_color').css('color', color); // will change the color of text
    $('#text_color').val( color );        // will change the hex value of textbox
}
```